# TensorFlow: is it possible to reduce sum while ignoring the NaN values?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have a 2-D tensor of `(batch_size, loss_dim)` and I hope to get the sum of each of the loss dimensions for each data sample, which can be done with `tf.reduce_mean(tensor, axis=-1)`.

However, what if there are NaN values in my tensor and I want to simply ignore those NaNs when calculating the sum? Does anyone know how to do that?

PS. I know that we can use `tf.boolean_mask` to fiter out the NaNs, but if I simply do `tensor = tf.boolean_mask(tensor, tf.logical_not(tf.is_nan(tensor))`, the output will be squashed into a single dimension, which is not what I want.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`tf.where()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) to replace the NaN values in `tensor` with zero while retaining the original shape:

```
tensor = ...

# Replace all NaN values with 0.0.
tensor_without_nans = tf.where(tf.is_nan(tensor), tf.zeros_like(tensor), tensor)

sum_ignoring_nans = tf.reduce_sum(tensor_without_nans, axis=-1)
```